Where do the prices of token, displayed in Metamask and on Block Explorers, come from?
When you have tokens in your wallet, and view them in a wallet application like Metamask or via public block explorers like Etherscan, PolygonScan etc, you can see a dollar value for the tokens.
Where is the price data coming from?
I cannot find information about it.
Thanks

They haven't mentioned the exact names of the sources though, like who uses what. But possibly, they retrieve the data using the oracle data feeds from sources like Chainlink, Pyth, API3, etc.
